# Allowing a user to type in a text box on a report

Tags: ms-access

On my report I want the user to be able to type in some miscellaneous notes before it is printed out, so I put a transparent text box on the report. However, when I type anything in the text box and click on something else, the text disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using a report for data entry is wrong. This should happen on the form that launches the report.

Comment: I know, but this report is generating a list of titles, sometimes hundreds. And there are a few times when one might need to have an asterisk next to it, but then on the next report it won't need the asterisk. So I thought it would be easier to add an "invisible" text box on the report that the user knows about and can edit when necessary.

Comment: Cannot enter data on reports, period. If you want to allow users to enter different value for each record then must save to table.